# Media Keys of MX Keys Not Working After Installing Logitech Options

Tags: keyboard, logitech, logitech-gaming-software, media-keys

I recently purchased this MX Keys and MX Master combo and was excited to use the keyboard to its full potential but the media keys is not working after I installed the Logitech options software.

> There is not much research available about it online. So, I am kind of
> desperate. Some guy suggested to alter the .xml file of the options
> software but I have no idea what kind of an edit is needed. Any help
> is welcome at this point. I have pasted the .xml code below for anyone
> to look.

```
  <features>
    <feature id="0x1000">
      <params>
        <param name="numberOfLevels" value="4" />
        <param name="flags" value="4" />
        <param name="nominalBatteryLife" value="49158" />
        <param name="batteryCriticalLife" value="10" />
      </params>
      <controlids />
      <fn_controlids />
      <gestures />
      <fn_gestures />
      <events />
    </feature>
    <feature id="0x1b04">
      <params />
      <controlids>
        <controlid rawxy="0" rawwheel="0" id="0x000a" reprogrammable="true" type="hotkey" taskidlist="calculatorList">
          <task minver="10" id="0x10045" class="virtualkeyex">
            <params alt="0" configure="0" ctrl="1" shift="0" vkey="37" win="1" prs="300" pss="30" />
          </task>
          <remappableids />
          <actions />
        </controlid>
        <controlid rawxy="0" rawwheel="0" id="0x006e" reprogrammable="true" type="fkey" fpos="5" taskidlist="showdesktopTaskidList">
          <task id="0x0043" class="keystroke">
            <params command="*d" />
          </task>
          <remappableids />
          <actions />
        </controlid>
        <controlid rawxy="0" rawwheel="0" id="0x006f" reprogrammable="true" type="hotkey" taskidlist="lockScreenTaskidList">
          <task id="0x0044" class="powermanagement">
            <params command="lockpc" />
          </task>
          <remappableids />
          <actions />
        </controlid>
        <controlid rawxy="0" rawwheel="0" id="0x00bf" reprogrammable="true" type="hotkey" taskidlist="printscreenTaskidList">
          <task divert="0" id="0x009b" class="donothing">
            <params />
          </task>
          <remappableids />
          <actions />
        </controlid>
        <controlid rawxy="0" rawwheel="0" id="0x00c7" reprogrammable="true" type="fkey" fpos="1" taskidlist="brightnessDownTaskidlist">
          <task id="0x10004" class="filelauncher">
            <params configure="1" exe="C:\Windows\System32\Taskmgr.exe" />
          </task>
          <remappableids />
          <actions />
        </controlid>
        <controlid rawxy="0" rawwheel="0" id="0x00c8" reprogrammable="true" type="fkey" fpos="2" taskidlist="brightnessUpTaskidlist">
          <task id="0x10004" class="filelauncher">
            <params configure="1" exe="C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\NVIDIACorp.NVIDIAControlPanel_8.1.961.0_x64__56jybvy8sckqj\nvcplui.exe" />
          </task>
          <remappableids />
          <actions />
        </controlid>
        <controlid generic="1" rawxy="0" rawwheel="0" id="0x00d1" reprogrammable="false" type="hotkey">
          <task id="0xffff" class="donothing">
            <params />
          </task>
          <remappableids />
          <actions />
        </controlid>
        <controlid generic="1" rawxy="0" rawwheel="0" id="0x00d2" reprogrammable="false" type="hotkey">
          <task id="0xffff" class="donothing">
            <params />
          </task>
          <remappableids />
          <actions />
        </controlid>
        <controlid generic="1" rawxy="0" rawwheel="0" id="0x00d3" reprogrammable="false" type="hotkey">
          <task duplicate="45" id="0x00b0" class="keystroke">
            <params command7="*f" command8="*q" command10="*s" />
          </task>
          <remappableids />
          <actions />
        </controlid>
        <controlid rawxy="0" rawwheel="0" id="0x00e0" reprogrammable="true" type="fkey" fpos="3" taskidlist="taskviewTaskIdlist">
          <task id="0x10009" class="filelauncher">
            <params configure="1" exe="D:\GM\System Folders\Desktop" lookuppath="1" foldername="D:\GM\System Folders\Desktop" openfolder="1" />
          </task>
          <remappableids />
          <actions />
        </controlid>
        <controlid rawxy="0" rawwheel="0" id="0x00e1" reprogrammable="true" type="fkey" fpos="4" taskidlist="actionCenterTaskIdlist">
          <task id="0x000a" class="filelauncher">
            <params commandlineargs="" exe="calc.exe" lookuppath="1" />
          </task>
          <remappableids />
          <actions />
        </controlid>
        <controlid rawxy="0" rawwheel="0" id="0x00e2" reprogrammable="true" type="fkey" fpos="6" taskidlist="backlightdownTaskIdlist">
          <task divert="0" id="0x00c1" class="virtualkey">
            <params />
          </task>
          <remappableids />
          <actions />
        </controlid>
        <controlid rawxy="0" rawwheel="0" id="0x00e3" reprogrammable="true" type="fkey" fpos="7" taskidlist="backlightupTaskIdlist">
          <task divert="0" id="0x00c2" class="virtualkey">
            <params />
          </task>
          <remappableids />
          <actions />
        </controlid>
        <controlid rawxy="0" rawwheel="0" id="0x00e4" reprogrammable="true" type="fkey" fpos="8" taskidlist="previousTrackTaskIdlist">
          <id="0x0006" class="media">
            <params command="previous" />
          </task>
          <remappableids />
          <actions />
        </controlid>
        <controlid rawxy="0" rawwheel="0" id="0x00e5" reprogrammable="true" type="fkey" fpos="9" taskidlist="playpauseTrackTaskIdlist">
          <id="0x0004" class="media">
            <params command="play_pause" />
          </task>
          <remappableids />
          <actions />
        </controlid>
        <controlid rawxy="0" rawwheel="0" id="0x00e6" reprogrammable="true" type="fkey" fpos="10" taskidlist="nextTrackTaskIdlist">
          <id="0x0005" class="media">
            <params command="next" />
          </task>
          <remappableids />
          <actions />
        </controlid>
        <controlid rawxy="0" rawwheel="0" id="0x00e7" reprogrammable="true" type="fkey" fpos="11" taskidlist="muteTaskIdlist">
          <task id="0x0003" class="volumecommand">
            <params command="volmute" />
          </task>
          <remappableids />
          <actions />
        </controlid>
        <controlid rawxy="0" rawwheel="0" id="0x00e8" reprogrammable="true" type="fkey" fpos="12" taskidlist="volDownTaskIdlist">
          <task id="0x0002" class="volumecommand">
            <params command="voldown" />
          </task>
          <remappableids />
          <actions />
        </controlid>
        <controlid rawxy="0" rawwheel="0" id="0x00e9" reprogrammable="true" type="hotkey" taskidlist="volUpTaskIdlist">
          <task id="0x0001" class="volumecommand">
            <params command="volup" />
          </task>
          <remappableids />
          <actions />
        </controlid>
        <controlid rawxy="0" rawwheel="0" id="0x00ea" reprogrammable="true" type="hotkey" taskidlist="appMenuTaskIdlist">
          <task minver="10" id="0x10044" class="virtualkeyex">
            <params alt="0" configure="0" ctrl="1" shift="0" vkey="39" win="1" prs="300" pss="30" />
          </task>
          <remappableids />
          <actions />
        </controlid>
        <controlid rawxy="0" rawwheel="0" id="0x00eb" reprogrammable="false" type="hotkey">
          <task id="0xffff" class="donothing">
            <params />
          </task>
          <remappableids />
          <actions />
        </controlid>
        <controlid rawxy="0" rawwheel="0" id="0x00ec" reprogrammable="false" type="hotkey">
          <task id="0xffff" class="donothing">
            <params />
          </task>
          <remappableids />
          <actions />
        </controlid>
      </controlids>
      <fn_controlids />
      <gestures />
      <fn_gestures />
      <events />
    </feature>
    <feature id="0x1814">
      <params>
        <param name="nbHost" value="3" />
      </params>
      <controlids />
      <fn_controlids />
      <gestures />
      <fn_gestures />
      <events />
    </feature>
    <feature id="0x1815">
      <params>
        <param name="nbHost" value="3" />
        <param name="eQuadHDCapability" value="0" />
        <param name="USBHDCapability" value="0" />
        <param name="BTHDCapability" value="1" />
        <param name="BLEHDCapability" value="0" />
        <param name="GetNameCapability" value="1" />
        <param name="SetNameCapability" value="1" />
        <param name="MoveHostCapability" value="0" />
        <param name="DeleteHostCapability" value="0" />
      </params>
      <controlids />
      <fn_controlids />
      <gestures />
      <fn_gestures />
      <events />
    </feature>
    <feature id="0x1982">
      <params>
        <param name="enableBacklight" value="1" />
        <param name="wow" value="1" />
        <param name="powerSave" value="1" />
      </params>
      <controlids />
      <fn_controlids />
      <gestures />
      <fn_gestures />
      <events />
    </feature>
    <feature id="0x40a3">
      <params>
        <param name="fnInversionState" value="1" />
        <param name="fnInversionDefaultState" value="1" />
      </params>
      <controlids />
      <fn_controlids />
      <gestures />
      <fn_gestures />
      <events />
    </feature>
    <feature id="0x4521">
      <params>
        <param name="winKey" value="0" />
        <param name="insertKey" value="0" />
        <param name="scrollLockKey" value="0" />
        <param name="numLockKey" value="0" />
        <param name="capsLockKey" value="0" />
      </params>
      <controlids />
      <fn_controlids />
      <gestures />
      <fn_gestures />
      <events />
    </feature>
    <feature id="0x4531">
      <params>
        <param name="nbHost" value="3" />
        <param name="osDetectionCapability" value="1" />
        <param name="setHostPlatformCapability" value="1" />
        <param name="autoHostSwitch" value="1" />
      </params>
      <controlids />
      <fn_controlids />
      <gestures />
      <fn_gestures />
      <events />
    </feature>
  </features>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an easy fix to this. Just add the `divert values` to the .xml file which are missing in the code you have shown. If you look a little closer, the keys which are not working are missing one value compared to the rest of the keys and that's why it is not working the way it is supposed to. Logitech should have fixed it by now.

I have owned the same keyboard for more than a year now and this issue is as old as the keyboard itself.

You can try this code and let me know if it works for you.

```
  <features>
<feature id="0x1000">
  <params>
    <param name="numberOfLevels" value="4" />
    <param name="flags" value="4" />
    <param name="nominalBatteryLife" value="49158" />
    <param name="batteryCriticalLife" value="10" />
  </params>
  <controlids />
  <fn_controlids />
  <gestures />
  <fn_gestures />
  <events />
</feature>
<feature id="0x1b04">
  <params />
  <controlids>
    <controlid rawxy="0" rawwheel="0" id="0x000a" reprogrammable="true" type="hotkey" taskidlist="calculatorList">
      <task minver="10" id="0x10045" class="virtualkeyex">
        <params alt="0" configure="0" ctrl="1" shift="0" vkey="37" win="1" prs="300" pss="30" />
      </task>
      <remappableids />
      <actions />
    </controlid>
    <controlid rawxy="0" rawwheel="0" id="0x006e" reprogrammable="true" type="fkey" fpos="5" taskidlist="showdesktopTaskidList">
      <task id="0x0043" class="keystroke">
        <params command="*d" />
      </task>
      <remappableids />
      <actions />
    </controlid>
    <controlid rawxy="0" rawwheel="0" id="0x006f" reprogrammable="true" type="hotkey" taskidlist="lockScreenTaskidList">
      <task id="0x0044" class="powermanagement">
        <params command="lockpc" />
      </task>
      <remappableids />
      <actions />
    </controlid>
    <controlid rawxy="0" rawwheel="0" id="0x00bf" reprogrammable="true" type="hotkey" taskidlist="printscreenTaskidList">
      <task divert="0" id="0x009b" class="donothing">
        <params />
      </task>
      <remappableids />
      <actions />
    </controlid>
    <controlid rawxy="0" rawwheel="0" id="0x00c7" reprogrammable="true" type="fkey" fpos="1" taskidlist="brightnessDownTaskidlist">
      <task id="0x10004" class="filelauncher">
        <params configure="1" exe="C:\Windows\System32\Taskmgr.exe" />
      </task>
      <remappableids />
      <actions />
    </controlid>
    <controlid rawxy="0" rawwheel="0" id="0x00c8" reprogrammable="true" type="fkey" fpos="2" taskidlist="brightnessUpTaskidlist">
      <task id="0x10004" class="filelauncher">
        <params configure="1" exe="C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\NVIDIACorp.NVIDIAControlPanel_8.1.961.0_x64__56jybvy8sckqj\nvcplui.exe" />
      </task>
      <remappableids />
      <actions />
    </controlid>
    <controlid generic="1" rawxy="0" rawwheel="0" id="0x00d1" reprogrammable="false" type="hotkey">
      <task id="0xffff" class="donothing">
        <params />
      </task>
      <remappableids />
      <actions />
    </controlid>
    <controlid generic="1" rawxy="0" rawwheel="0" id="0x00d2" reprogrammable="false" type="hotkey">
      <task id="0xffff" class="donothing">
        <params />
      </task>
      <remappableids />
      <actions />
    </controlid>
    <controlid generic="1" rawxy="0" rawwheel="0" id="0x00d3" reprogrammable="false" type="hotkey">
      <task duplicate="45" id="0x00b0" class="keystroke">
        <params command7="*f" command8="*q" command10="*s" />
      </task>
      <remappableids />
      <actions />
    </controlid>
    <controlid rawxy="0" rawwheel="0" id="0x00e0" reprogrammable="true" type="fkey" fpos="3" taskidlist="taskviewTaskIdlist">
      <task id="0x10009" class="filelauncher">
        <params configure="1" exe="D:\GM\System Folders\Desktop" lookuppath="1" foldername="D:\GM\System Folders\Desktop" openfolder="1" />
      </task>
      <remappableids />
      <actions />
    </controlid>
    <controlid rawxy="0" rawwheel="0" id="0x00e1" reprogrammable="true" type="fkey" fpos="4" taskidlist="actionCenterTaskIdlist">
      <task id="0x000a" class="filelauncher">
        <params commandlineargs="" exe="calc.exe" lookuppath="1" />
      </task>
      <remappableids />
      <actions />
    </controlid>
    <controlid rawxy="0" rawwheel="0" id="0x00e2" reprogrammable="true" type="fkey" fpos="6" taskidlist="backlightdownTaskIdlist">
      <task divert="0" id="0x00c1" class="virtualkey">
        <params />
      </task>
      <remappableids />
      <actions />
    </controlid>
    <controlid rawxy="0" rawwheel="0" id="0x00e3" reprogrammable="true" type="fkey" fpos="7" taskidlist="backlightupTaskIdlist">
      <task divert="0" id="0x00c2" class="virtualkey">
        <params />
      </task>
      <remappableids />
      <actions />
    </controlid>
    <controlid rawxy="0" rawwheel="0" id="0x00e4" reprogrammable="true" type="fkey" fpos="8" taskidlist="previousTrackTaskIdlist">
      <task divert="0" id="0x0006" class="media">
        <params command="previous" />
      </task>
      <remappableids />
      <actions />
    </controlid>
    <controlid rawxy="0" rawwheel="0" id="0x00e5" reprogrammable="true" type="fkey" fpos="9" taskidlist="playpauseTrackTaskIdlist">
      <task divert="0" id="0x0004" class="media">
        <params command="play_pause" />
      </task>
      <remappableids />
      <actions />
    </controlid>
    <controlid rawxy="0" rawwheel="0" id="0x00e6" reprogrammable="true" type="fkey" fpos="10" taskidlist="nextTrackTaskIdlist">
      <task divert="0" id="0x0005" class="media">
        <params command="next" />
      </task>
      <remappableids />
      <actions />
    </controlid>
    <controlid rawxy="0" rawwheel="0" id="0x00e7" reprogrammable="true" type="fkey" fpos="11" taskidlist="muteTaskIdlist">
      <task id="0x0003" class="volumecommand">
        <params command="volmute" />
      </task>
      <remappableids />
      <actions />
    </controlid>
    <controlid rawxy="0" rawwheel="0" id="0x00e8" reprogrammable="true" type="fkey" fpos="12" taskidlist="volDownTaskIdlist">
      <task id="0x0002" class="volumecommand">
        <params command="voldown" />
      </task>
      <remappableids />
      <actions />
    </controlid>
    <controlid rawxy="0" rawwheel="0" id="0x00e9" reprogrammable="true" type="hotkey" taskidlist="volUpTaskIdlist">
      <task id="0x0001" class="volumecommand">
        <params command="volup" />
      </task>
      <remappableids />
      <actions />
    </controlid>
    <controlid rawxy="0" rawwheel="0" id="0x00ea" reprogrammable="true" type="hotkey" taskidlist="appMenuTaskIdlist">
      <task minver="10" id="0x10044" class="virtualkeyex">
        <params alt="0" configure="0" ctrl="1" shift="0" vkey="39" win="1" prs="300" pss="30" />
      </task>
      <remappableids />
      <actions />
    </controlid>
    <controlid rawxy="0" rawwheel="0" id="0x00eb" reprogrammable="false" type="hotkey">
      <task id="0xffff" class="donothing">
        <params />
      </task>
      <remappableids />
      <actions />
    </controlid>
    <controlid rawxy="0" rawwheel="0" id="0x00ec" reprogrammable="false" type="hotkey">
      <task id="0xffff" class="donothing">
        <params />
      </task>
      <remappableids />
      <actions />
    </controlid>
  </controlids>
  <fn_controlids />
  <gestures />
  <fn_gestures />
  <events />
</feature>
<feature id="0x1814">
  <params>
    <param name="nbHost" value="3" />
  </params>
  <controlids />
  <fn_controlids />
  <gestures />
  <fn_gestures />
  <events />
</feature>
<feature id="0x1815">
  <params>
    <param name="nbHost" value="3" />
    <param name="eQuadHDCapability" value="0" />
    <param name="USBHDCapability" value="0" />
    <param name="BTHDCapability" value="1" />
    <param name="BLEHDCapability" value="0" />
    <param name="GetNameCapability" value="1" />
    <param name="SetNameCapability" value="1" />
    <param name="MoveHostCapability" value="0" />
    <param name="DeleteHostCapability" value="0" />
  </params>
  <controlids />
  <fn_controlids />
  <gestures />
  <fn_gestures />
  <events />
</feature>
<feature id="0x1982">
  <params>
    <param name="enableBacklight" value="1" />
    <param name="wow" value="1" />
    <param name="powerSave" value="1" />
  </params>
  <controlids />
  <fn_controlids />
  <gestures />
  <fn_gestures />
  <events />
</feature>
<feature id="0x40a3">
  <params>
    <param name="fnInversionState" value="1" />
    <param name="fnInversionDefaultState" value="1" />
  </params>
  <controlids />
  <fn_controlids />
  <gestures />
  <fn_gestures />
  <events />
</feature>
<feature id="0x4521">
  <params>
    <param name="winKey" value="0" />
    <param name="insertKey" value="0" />
    <param name="scrollLockKey" value="0" />
    <param name="numLockKey" value="0" />
    <param name="capsLockKey" value="0" />
  </params>
  <controlids />
  <fn_controlids />
  <gestures />
  <fn_gestures />
  <events />
</feature>
<feature id="0x4531">
  <params>
    <param name="nbHost" value="3" />
    <param name="osDetectionCapability" value="1" />
    <param name="setHostPlatformCapability" value="1" />
    <param name="autoHostSwitch" value="1" />
  </params>
  <controlids />
  <fn_controlids />
  <gestures />
  <fn_gestures />
  <events />
</feature>
```

Do save a copy of the original file before editing anything! Restart if nothing seems to change after the edit.

Comment: First of all, thanks for responding so quickly. I am checking the code right now and will let you know if it works the way I want it to.

Comment: I just tried the code you sent and it is still not working. Man, I got excited since you own the same keyboard.

Comment: @G.M.

That should have worked. Check if the edits were saved or not. And also restart your PC and then let me know.

Comment: The edits were saved. Just restarted the machine and now, the keys are working. Wow, can't believe this was that easy. Thanks for the help.